# php: convert an array obtained from a form

Tags: php, arrays

in PHP, I have an array that is structured as follows:

```
Array
(
    [nom-1] => martin
    [prenom-1] => bidule
    [date-1] => 1961-01-10
    [nom-2] => dupont
    [prenom-2] => machin
    [date-2] => 1972-02-20
    [nom-7] => durand
    [prenom-7] => truc
    [date-7] => 1983-03-30
    ...
)
```

and I would get this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => array ( [nom] => martin
                   [prenom] => bidule
                   [date] => 1961-01-10
                 )
    [2] => array ( [nom] => dupont
                   [prenom] => machin
                   [date] => 1972-02-20
                 )
    [7] => array ( [nom] => durand
                   [prenom] => truc
                   [date] => 1983-03-30
                 )
    ...
)
```

I think there may be a simple solution with a php function that I would not know.

Thank you kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick.

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/^[a-z]+?-\d+?$/', $key)) {
        preg_match('/^([a-z]+?)-(\d+?)$/', $key, $match);
        $n = (int)$match[2];
        if(!isset($newArr[$n])) {
            $newArr[$n] = array();
        }
        $newArr[$n][$match[1]] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

But i would use `nom[]`, `prenom[]` and `date[]` as the name on the input instead, then you get an array in the `$_POST` variable for where it's multiple inputs with the same name.

Comment: The other approach that has been proposed is similar to what I had done

but I will test this approach tomorrow.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

here is the another one:

```
$a=array
(
    'nom-1' => 'martin',
    'prenom-1' => 'bidule',
    'date-1' => '1961-01-10'

    );
// function refactor($a){
    $output=array();
 foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
     $keyData=explode("-", $key);
     $output[$keyData[1]][$keyData[0]]=$value;
 }
 print_r($output);
```

Comment: I wrote exactly the same code ... with one difference: "preg_split" instead of "explode" and it did not work. I guess I used wrong "preg_split".

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you try above code? It should work with explode function .. see the output `Array ( [1] => Array ( [nom] => martin [prenom] => bidule [date] => 1961-01-10 ) )`

Comment: My english is bad: I meant that the code is ok with "explode" ... but not with "preg_split" (that I did not use properly).

Comment: Y dont u use explode??

Answer (score 0):

Without regex.

```
$array = Array(
    'nom-1' => 'martin',
    'prenom-1' => 'bidule',
    'date-1' => '1961-01-10',
    'nom-2' => 'dupont',
    'prenom-2' => 'machin',
    'date-2' => '1972-02-20',
    'nom-7' => 'durand',
    'prenom-7' => 'truc',
    'date-7' => '1983-03-30'
);

$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $num = substr($key, strpos($key, '-')+1);
    if (!isset($newArray[$num]))
        $newArray[$num] = array();

    array_push($newArray[$num], array(substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '-')) => $value));
}
```

Comment: But this won't work on n < 10, so nom-15 will not work.

Comment: @Karl you are right, see my updated answer. This will work with more than one digit.